# How to dock a window the the left using autohotkey?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

In Windows 7, you can drag a window to the leftmost screen position and it will dock itself there, expanding to the full height of the screen and half its width.

Is there an easy way to do this using AutoHotKey?

Comment: I don't have Win7 to test on, but try `ControlSend,, #{Left}, A` where A means the active window, or you can replace it with a title. [ControlSend](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided the best way to do it - especially since I have two monitors and might want a window docked to a specific one - is to dock it manually first, then get the coordinates and width/height of the docked window using Window Spy. Then I can use the WinMove command to send it to that position.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but I just had the same problem, needed to integrate window docking in a chain of AHK commands. This worked for me:

```
Send {LWin down}{Left}{LWin up}
```

If you're using Alt or Ctrl in your shortkey, you'll need to use KeyWait like:

```
KeyWait Ctrl
Send {LWin down}{Left}{LWin up}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Emmm, not sure if this is what you're looking for but windowskey+left will dock the current window on the left. You don't even need autohotkey to do it.

Comment: Ha - Yes, I realize that I don't need AutoHotKey to dock a window, but I want docking a window to be part of a series of AutoHotKey commands that I'm executing: "open this application; dock it to the left; open this other application; dock it to the right; etc."